# How to let the tooltip be displayed for longer time when user hovers over a line chart drawn in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The tooltip that gets displayed after user hovers on a line chart in chart.js stays  for a short time,about 2-3 secs. I want the tooltip to be displayed till the time mouse pointer is over that same point.

Comment: please check this link        https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html

Comment: Hi. I checked the link. Couldn't find any option that does the required job.

Comment: @ArpitJain I checked the link. Couldn't find any option that does the required job.